# Solr nested data import

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a master/detail table that I would like to import in Solr so I can query it.
Now it appears to me that only the first row of the detail table is imported.

How do I import all rows from the detail table?

I currently have something like this in my data import handler query:

```
<entity name="master" query="SELECT id, name, description,
          FROM master WHERE isapproved = 1">

<!-- snip -->

<entity name="details" query="SELECT sku,description,price 
                               FROM details WHERE masterid='${master.id}'">
    <field column="sku name="sku" />
</entity>
```

To make it a bit more difficult, sometimes there are only master rows without corresponding detail rows. So I could not reverse the query (select detail first and then master) because that would leave me without the master data.

What is a good solution?

Comment: About your problem `only the first row of the detail table is imported` could you list your schema.xml? Probably you missed the `multiValued="true"`. About the `So I could not reverse the query` that depends, what do you want to list as search results? The master or the details?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't specify it as multivalued. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly I do not see your `schema.xml`, but it is likely that you forgot to mark your document attribute as `multiValued="true"` there. In that case Solr would only fetch the first value and skip the rest.